# Panel is not coming on top, Z-index is not working for panels

Tags: asp.net, webforms, panel

I have two panels in my asp.net project. Each having controls of their own. The 2nd panel is contained within the 1st panel. Even if i give lower z-index for the 2nd panel, it is always visible above the 1st panel. Please find code below.

`

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Panelshow.aspx.vb" Inherits="paneltest.Panelshow" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
          .panelbg {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 700px;
            background-color: palegreen;
               z-index:300;
           position:relative;
         
        }
          .pan2{
              top: 200px;
              left : 200px;
   background-color:aqua;
               z-index:1;
           position:relative;
          }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" CssClass="panelbg" runat="server">
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="pan2" runat="server">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you wish the two panel stacking on top of each other. both panel should stand on the same level, not one within another. for example:

```
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" CssClass="panelbg" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="pan2" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Then your css will make both elements have the **position of absolute** for the z-index to take effect:

```
.panelbg {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: palegreen;
    z-index: 300;
    position: absolute;
}

.pan2 {
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Sincere thanks, position:absolute worked

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to vote

Comment: u can select my answer as "answered"

Answer (score 0):

You have a answer, but I will explain how this works.

Think of each "div" (or panel - same thing) as a sheet of paper.

You can stack paper on top of each other.

but, RULE IS:

Stuff you put on EACH sheet of paper can't have a lower z-index then the sheet of paper!!!

So, you nested your div/panels.

So, text, input boxes, anything on ONE sheet of paper can NOT have a lower index then the sheet of paper.

So, in your example?

You don't have 2 sheets of paper, you have ONE sheet of paper with stuff inside!

Stuff inside a sheet of paper can't have a lower z-index - it will not work.

And "stuff" inside ONE sheet of paper ALSO means more div's or more panels.

So, you need 2 sheets of paper so to speak, or better said you can't "nest" the  2nd div/panel inside of the first (well, you can, but any element in/on/placed on that one sheet of paper can't have a lower z-index).

You for this metaphor only have ONE sheet of paper (the first panel). What ever you drop inside/on this sheet of paper can't have a lower z-index.

If you need elements with a lower z-index, you need two sheets of paper - not nested.

So, this would work:

```
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" CssClass="panelbg" runat="server" >
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />            
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="pan2" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </asp:Panel>
```

So, above can be thought as 2 sheets of paper, each with stuff inside. But each paper cannot have elements with a lower z-index (it does not work).

however, if you looking to hide/show that nested element, then use style=display:none to hide, and style="display:in-line (or normal) to show.

So, elements placed on our so called "paper" can each have higher, or lower z-index, but NONE can have a z-index lower then the sheet of paper they are placed on/in.

To move such elements LOWER then the paper/sheet they are placed on you thus need 2 separate sheets of paper (2 divs/panels - not nested).

and because they are not nested, then you need to use absolute.

So, say this:

```
<style>
    .panelbg {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 500px;
        height: 700px;
        background-color: palegreen;
        z-index: 300;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .pan2 {
        top: 200px;
        left: 200px;
        width: 600px;
        background-color: aqua;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

and

```
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" CssClass="panelbg" runat="server" >
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />            
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="pan2" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </asp:Panel>
```

and now this:

[image]

Since we now have 2 sheets of paper, then I need to use absolute position to "stack" the 2 sheets on top of each other. Relative will not work, since we now have 2 separate sheets of paper (2 div/panels).

thus, our simple rule:

stuff dropped into that sheet of paper can't have ANY element with a lower z-index then the sheet of paper being used.

Comment: Sincere thanks, it works. Don't have enough reputation to vote